# Is it possible to pass two arguments in commandlinesArgs?

Tags: java, maven

I am working on a new project and I need to convert several `idl` files using the `idlpp` command.

I work under IntelliJ 2020.1 using Maven.

Here is my code (just plugin exec-maven-plugin) :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>${idlpp_exec}</executable>
                <workingDirectory>${gen-idl-dir}</workingDirectory>
                <commandlineArgs>${example-idl}</commandlineArgs>
                <commandlineArgs>${basic-idl}</commandlineArgs>
                <commandlineArgs>${weather-idl}</commandlineArgs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

It works well on if I place a single `commandlineArgs` but the problem is that I have several `idl` files. It is possible to compile everything in a single `commandlineArgs` or is it impossible ??

Thanks

EDIT

I forgot to specify here is what is behind the calls `${}` :

```
<gen-idl-dir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/idl/</gen-idl-dir>
<example-idl>-l java -S "../../../../IDL_Files/Chat.idl"</example-idl>
<basic-types-idl>-l java -S "../../../../IDL_Files/Basic_Types.idl"</basic-types-idl>
<common-types-idl>-l java -S "../../../../IDL_Files/Common_Types.idl"</common-types-idl>
```

The command `<commandlineArgs>${example-idl} ${basic-types-idl}</commandlineArgs>` does not work either because of the calls how I could fix that ??

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [plugin document](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html), multiple arguments in `commandlineArgs` are separated by space,

> Arguments separated by space for the executed program. For example: "-j 20"

So you should try with:

```
<commandlineArgs>${example-idl} ${basic-idl} ${weather-idl}</commandlineArgs>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I've edited my question for more details.

Comment: Can you show the full command line you want ask maven execute in your question? Alternative, I think you may create a shell/batch script, and ask maven exec plugin call script.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the Arguments using space.  Use `-j 30`   or `-j 10`  Depending on the spaces you wish to have.  This is also how we format in java except they add a % before.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I've edited my question for more details.